# Erasing an elemnt from a 3D vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, element, erase

So, I have a vector, containing vectors which contain vectors which contain integers, essentially acting as a 3D array. I have declared it as so:

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> maxtrix;
...
int size = 16;
vector<int> intial; 
inital.assign(size, 0); // fill a vector with 0s depending on size
vector<vector<int>> secondInitial;
secondInitial.assign(size, initial); // so now the 2d array holds the inital empty vector
matrix.assign(size,secondInitial); // an array of the 2d arrays -> 3d array.
```

I can therefore only access the matrix via

```
matrix[x][y][z];
```

but I need to be able to erase elements like:

```
initial.erase(0)
```

However I have tried an am unable to in the way of :

```
matrix.erase([a][b][c]);
```

I am not sure how else I could access the 'deepest' level of the vector to remove elements without it being declared.

I have tried to search how to do it for a 2D vector an extrapolate out for a 3D vector but I am stuck. Thanks.

Comment: You need to call `erase` for one of the inner vectors. For example: `matrix[x][y].erase(matrix[x][y].begin() + z, matrix[x][y].begin() + z + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

I would guess something like this would work:

```
matrix[x][y].erase(matrix[x][y].begin() + z);
```

And then you substitute in whatever numbers you want for `x`, `y`, and `z`.